# How to Count Records in a Dimension?

Tags: crossfilter

I'm trying to convert an app to use Crossfilter and have run into a problem.

My data looks something like the following:

```
Threshold:  0.7       

ID  Category A  Category B  Category C    Any category above threshold?
1   0.21        0.83        0.83          TRUE
2   0.38        0.68        0.47          FALSE
3   0.72        0.58        0.01          TRUE
4   0.95        0.62        0.01          TRUE
5   0.61        0.75        0.27          TRUE

Category Above threshold                  Total above threshold
    2           2           1             4
```

I have a global threshold value and a number of categories (A through C). The global threshold determines which rows are filtered (all except 2). Then of the filtered rows, for each category I need to calculate the number of rows with a value above the threshold (A: 2, B: 2, C: 1). The threshold can change dynamically.

I have not been able to figure out how to maintain category counts without iterating over all filtered rows (expensive!) each time the threshold changes. Can someone suggest a better approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know the possible thresholds before-hand, you can create dimensions with accessors that return boolean values indicating whether a record exceeds the threshold or not. Otherwise, I'd say just iterate over all filtered rows, either by creating new dimensions or outside of the Crossfilter using the output of `dimension.top` or `crossfilter.allFiltered`.